# Cannot install git-core using macports

Tags: mac, macports

Snow Leopard 10.6.4
mac ports 1.9.1

I have just installed macports and I want to install git-core.

However, I get the following errors:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for git-core
--->  Dependencies to be installed: python26 db46 gdbm readline sqlite3 rsync popt
--->  Building db46
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed
Log for db46 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/main.log
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: python26 db46 gdbm readline sqlite3 rsync popt
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

I have tried doing a `port selfupdate` and a `port clean all` and then trying to install again. But still get the same problem.

This is my first time using mac ports.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

====== EDIT ====

```
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for db46): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
```

Comment: I think that question should be asked on http://serverfault.com instead here

Comment: You should look into the log file `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/...release_ports_databases_db46/main.log` and search error of Google if it is not trivial

Comment: Try installing some of those listed dependencies individually. Also make sure you're using port with sudo.

Comment: @CharlesB, I have edited my answer with that log.

Comment: @Ollie, Yes, I did try and install the db46. However, I got the same problem.

Comment: What is the full content of the log file?

Comment: Use Homebrew instead.

Comment: Or for git use the prebuilt version http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for db46): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install

is the first error in the log then I think you need to run the command with sudo

e.g.

```
sudo port install readline
```

Try readline as I think it is the simplest port

and I think superuser is the correct place for this not serverfault as macports can apply to one machine and is just for installing software. (I suppose [Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) might be a relevant site.